# Why is void returning a value?

Tags: c++, void

I can't understand one weird thing. Here is my program :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Swap(int *a , int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    int b=0;

    cout<<"Please enter integer A: ";
    cin>>a;

    cout<<"Please enter integer B: ";
    cin>>b;

    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"************Before Swap************\n";
    cout<<"Value of A ="<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"Value of B ="<<b<<endl;

    Swap (&a , &b);

    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"************After Swap*************\n";
    cout<<"Value of A ="<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"Value of B ="<<b<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now if you look at the function "Swap", I have used "void Swap". Therefore it must not return any value to main function (only "int" returns a value (at least that's what my teacher has taught me)). But if you execute it, the values are swaped in main function! How come ? Can anyone tell me how its possible ?

Comment: make sure you understand the difference between "pass by value" and "pass by reference"

Comment: return has a specific meaning in C++, If `Swap` said `return temp;` (for instance) that would be returning a value and that would not be allowed in a void function. What swap is doing is modifying variables passed to it via pointers. That's perfectly OK.

Comment: "only "int" returns a value" - it's the other way around. Only `void` does not return a value, anything else does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the function is NOT returning the value. It is just **accessing** the values through the variables' addresses and swapping them from their reference. Your code is right and now I have cleared your concept without any long explanation. That's all.

Answer (score 6):

Swap function in your example just swaps two integers, but does NOT return anything.

In order to check what function has retuned, you have to assign it to some variable, like this

```
int a = swap(&a, &b);
```

but this piece of code has an error because swap function doesn't return anything.

Another example:

```
int func() {
    return 18;
}

int main() {
    int a =  func();
    cout << a;
}
```

Is fine, cause variable a is int and function func returns an int.

Comment: what about `if(function())`? I do not assign the return value, of the function, but I check it.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski function() == false only if function() == 0. Otherwise function() == true. If function()'s return type is void, code will not compile

Answer (score 2):

`Swap` may not return any values, but it can still modify them. You're passing in pointers to two variables into the function. If you change the value the pointer maps to in the `Swap` function, that change persists throughout the program.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction. I'll make the correction in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.

Your `Swap` method does work with pointers, not real values.

In your main your are calling this method and tell it to swap the values in the variables. They are in the sme context at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks very similar to this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_pointer.htm

What it does it uses pointers addresses. You use them as parameters and then you use them to access the information stored at that location, which is the values of a and b, and then change them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstand what your teacher said.

What he/she said might be Swap() will not return value, but change value by passing address is still valid.

like this:

```
int Swap();
int GetReturnValue = Swap(); // Get return value from Swap()
```

Let's look the second one:

```
void Swap();
int GetReturnValue = Swap();
```

Though the second one might really get value, but this value is meaningless.

Sometimes, you will get a compiler warning if you do like the second one, GCC Compiler will report warnings about `casting`

Answer (score 1):

Swap procedure can only modify your variables because you've passed them by reference.

Remember procedures, unlike functions, cannot return a value.